# How to compute the cost of a Cloud ML job?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

My Cloud ML training job completed with the output:

```
"consumedMLUnits": 43.24
```

How do I use this information to determine the cost of the training job? I can't decide between the following two options:

1. According to [the pricing section of the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing#training), I should multiply $0.49 (since I am located in the US) by the number of ML units by the duration of the job (which was 4.5 hours). So:

   ```
   $0.49 x 43.24 x 4.5 = $95.3442
   ```
2. On the other hand, my experience has been that longer running training jobs lead to higher values for `consumedMLUnits`, which suggests to me that duration has already been incorporated into this metric. If so I think the calculation would be:

   ```
   $0.49 x 43.24 = $21.1876
   ```

Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2) is correct - duration has already been incorporated into this metric, hence the correct calculation is:

```
$0.49 x 43.24 = $21.1876
```